# Сортировка товара в Virtuemart 2.0.10

Tags: virtuemart, joomla

Всем здравствуйте! Есть магазин одежды на joomla 2.5.6 + Virtuemart 2.0.10
Если в категории товара выбрать "Сортировка по цене" (или по названию, по цене просто нагляднее) происходит "задвоение" некоторых товаров (в категории корсеты), т.е. я вижу один и тот же товара на разных страницах данной категории сейчас задваивается "Корсет клубный (2240)" причём, задваиваются не последние и первые товары страницы (что могло бы быть вызвано неправильными параметрами `limit` и `limitstart`) а в хаотичном порядке. Для эксперимента, я установил такую-же версию `joomla` и `virtueart` на отдельный сайт, добавил 2 десятка товаров и никакого задвоения при сортироваках по цене, названию или артикулу - не наблюдается. В админке увидел разницу

[image]

В админке тестового сайта данной колонки нет

[image]

Не могу понять что не так. Может быть кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой - подскажите. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выберите сперва категорию вверху в Filter